# "Import flask from Flask" stops working after deactivating env

Tags: flask, pip

already searched database within stockoverflow -- there are no answers to this question!

"Import flask from Flask" stops working after deactivating env

1. installed python3:

   - "python3 --version" -->returns Python 3.7.4

     2. installed virtualenv
   - "pip3 install virtualenv"
   - "virtualenv env"
   - "virtualenv --version"  --> returns 16.7.4

     3. activated virtual environment
   - "source env/b/activate"  --> creates (env) note at terminal prompt correctly

     4. installed flask in virtual environment
   - " pip3 install flask"

     5. In the python shell, `import flask` does not return an error.
     6. python program is:
        ...
        from flask import Flask
        app = Flask(__ name __)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    - return 'Hello, World!'
...

I get an error!
 7. the error is: "unable to import flask"

### ANY IDEAS ARE APPRECIATED.  THANK YOU

I am using the following to run program:

### export FLASK_APP=flask_blog.py

pip show flask  --> returns:  flask not found
pip3 show flask --> returns: flask version 1.1.1
pip doesn't find flask but pip3 does.  What does that mean?

Comment: Possible that you are running the file using python2?

Comment: Which operating system is this on?

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv venv` creates a virtual environment that uses Python 2. Since it isn't using Python 3, `pip3 install flask` uses the system pip3, which lives outside the virtual environment. This will install Flask outside of the virtual environment.

It's unclear how you're invoking Python. If you're typing `python3`, if you're getting the system `python3`, which will be able to import Flask.

Regardless, to correct this, remove `venv`, and build it again using

```
virtualenv --python=python3 venv
```

and then either activate the virtual environment, or use one of the wrappers that that virtual environment provides for you. e.g.,

```
venv/bin/pip install Flask
```

then

```
FLASK_APP=app.py venv/bin/flask run
```

Comment: David,  I followed your commands and they worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: David,  Is there a website or tutorial that can teach me about virtualenv?

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ is a good place to start. Note that many think that `pyenv` will replace `virtualenv`, but we're not there yet.